# Get method calls of IMethod through eclipse CallHierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, call-hierarchy

I am looking to get IMethod, IType or IJavaElement in which a IMethod is being called. I explored org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.callhierarchy.CallHierarchy.
I have written this code but its not giving me anything in wrapper or in location.
Please guide me.

```
public void getMethodCallers(IMethod[] methods){

CallHierarchy hierarchy = new CallHierarchy();
IJavaSearchScope searchScope= SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();
hierarchy.setSearchScope(searchScope);
CallLocation location = hierarchy.getCallLocation(method[0])
MethodWrapper [] wrapper = hierarchy.getCalleeRoots(methods);



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post describes in detail how to achieve this: [Java: Find all callers of a method – get all methods that call a particular method](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/find-all-callers-of-a-method/)